# Explicitly treat link as an absolute link?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, navigation

I have a control on one of my page which takes some user input (URL) and allows the user to test the link.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("URL") %>' Target="_blank">Click here to test link</asp:HyperLink>
```

The problem is if the user puts in the URL "google.com", then the link will be treated as "http://localhost/google.com". I have to put "http://www.google.com" for it to go to the right place.

Is it possible to treat the link like it is an absolute link in all cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

```
NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("URL", "http://{0}") %>'
```

**Edit:** if you want to add check whether it already contain `http://` then it should be like..

```
NavigateUrl=<%# Eval("URL").ToString().Contains("http://") == true ? Eval("URL") :
 "http://" + Eval("URL")  %>
```

Comment: would that work? what if the input already has http in it? what if its a secure (https) site or a ftp site?

Comment: @Muhammed:+1 == true is needless, right? @stickman dont expect to see any algorithm that finds the protocol from a raw url. thats completely pointless and impossible.

Comment: yah; you are right. I guess that will help him to understand :)

Comment: @naveen : I'm not trying to resolve the protocol. I want the DNS server to resolve the protocol, just like if I entered the exact URL into a browser. If I put http:// in front of a URL that would normally be resolved to https:// by the DNS, would it still resolve to a https address?

Comment: @Muhammad : I ended up using your solution, but instead I made it check for .Contains("://") like colebrand said. This is just in case they do put in https address, it won't go http://https/... Preferably I would like it to send just the url to the browser and let the browser handle it on it's own terms, but this is the probably the next best solution. Thanks.

Comment: @stickman: i have wrote something as an answer. its merely an explanation. i started as a comment but ended up in writing it up.

Answer (score 3):

Is this question of academic nature or do you have a problem to solve?

Firstly, the notion that http://www.google.com is the right place and http://localhost/google.com is incorrect is very wrong.

Your problem as I see is this.
When you pull urls from a datasource there are raw urls which ASP.NET Framework recognizes as relative URL. But you would like them to use their absolute uri.

But the problem is not with the framework as http://localhost/google.com could be a valid URL.
A good example for the same will be the site [builtWith](http://builtwith.com/). It has valid URLS like http://builtwith.com/facebook.com

And so, the problem is at the place where you have input the data. Why could you not place a small combo so that users could easily add the protocols and then append the url to it as shown below?

[image: A small example of the UI]

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. Firstly, yes it is a problem I have to solve. http://localhost/google.com is a valid url, in fact, I'm pretty sure anything is a valid URL, it just depends on how the DNS treats it. However, in this case, the user is asked to specify a link. Most users are going to assume it is an absolute link and not a relative one so taking them to http://localhost/google.com would not be what they want. I like the idea about the drop down box though, it may be an idea.

Comment: This assumption is not valid - `I'm pretty sure anything is a valid URL, it just depends on how the DNS treats`

Comment: @Alex : oh ok, can you show me an invalid URL that the DNS would not be able to resolve?

Comment: google.com is invalid URL. You can go to `http://urlvalidator.com/` and check it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments:

> What if it's a secure (https) site or an FTP site?

and

> Would that work? What if the input already has `http` in it? What if it's a secure (https) site or an FTP site?

and

> The problem is if the user puts in the URL "google.com", then the link will be treated as "http://localhost/google.com". I have to put "http://www.google.com" for it to go to the right place.
>
> Is it possible to treat the link like it is an absolute link in all cases?

You're asking for *magic*. We don't specialize in magic here. You have to specify *something* that lets you know that it can become a specific type of domain. Tell them if they don't specify the protocol you will as http:// and the rest of the time it's up to them to specify the protocol. It's all you can do.

As for determining if it's got a protocol, check `string.Contains("://")`, since that's what the browser is going to do anyway, more or less.

Comment: why is it magic? all I'm asking is that instead of putting http://localhost at the front of all links that don't begin with http, just enter whatever the link the user has specified in the new browser window and let it resolve itself.

Comment: no, that's not what you're asking. The spec on link urls is that if they don't start with a protocol, they are appended to the current path of the page as executing.

Comment: i still don't see why it is magic. Magic implies that there is some lack of information that prevents me from doing this. But there isn't - however the user has entered in as their URL, I want it to explicit the same behaviour as if they entered that URL into a browser.

Comment: WRONG. You are so wrong. Look, how do you know if it's http, https or ftp based on they gave you "google.com" ... protocol has nothing to do with DNS. How do you think protocols work? I love that you used my answer but accepted someone else's answer. You're not at all sure of what you want to do, except that you want it to magically know how to use the protocol. I'm more than willing to make this about education, but your pig headedness won't allow that, will it?

Comment: @jcolebrand : easy there mate, there's no need to be so aggressive. Like i said, I'm trying to replicate exactly what the browser does with the URL. I don't know how it does it, maybe it's the DNS or maybe it's the browser - what I've done makes some assumptions about the protocol, but I'm still not sure if it's the same assumption as what the browser uses. If it was "magic", typing in firefox "google.com" in the Run prompt would give me a 404.

Comment: @jcolebrand - I selected the other answer because he provided the actual code and I felt he was the most helpful. I did decide to tweak his code with your suggestion which is why you got an upvote.

Comment: The browser does use "magic", in the form of it tries http if no protocol is given, and it tries .com, .org, .net and a couple other tlds before it gives up, if it is so configured, for things like "server" or "example" or "microsoft". I know that it's magic because you don't know how it does it, but you know that it's technologically advanced. That's an old quote. But look, how do you know if someone tells you to check their website at ThatWebsiteDot and then you didn't hear the TLD, and can't ask them again, how do you find it? You have to look for it. What if you only get one chance?

Comment: You have to guess if you don't know for sure. Or you ask someone. In this case, you get to ask the user. My advice, given what all you've said, is to put a check on the field as it's being entered, and if the string they provided doesn't contain `://` then reject it and tell them to try again. If you DON'T DO THAT ONE THING, THEN YOU CANNOT MAKE WHAT YOU WANT TO HAPPEN HAPPEN. I DON'T CARE HOW MUCH YOU WANT TO, OR HOW SURE YOU ARE YOU CAN MAKE IT HAPPEN. Now, I will say that something like 95% of the time they want http:// and .com, but those are statistics on the average person. Your call.

Answer (score 1):

In your code-behind, check if the user input contains "http://" and append it if it doesn't. You can also use JavaScript to do this.

Comment: what if its a secure (https) site or a ftp site?

Comment: you check for both http and https.

Comment: Also, "prepend", not "append".